# Style all Buttons in a StackPanel the same way (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want that all Buttons in a StackPanel have the same style.

Is there a similar possibility like in HTML / CSS?

For example, this makes in HTML the text of all buttons in the div with the class myBox blue:

CSS

```
.myBox Button{
    color: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="myBox">
    <button type="button">1</button>
    <button type="button">2</button>
    <button type="button">3</button>
</div>
```

When I have now this StackPanel, how can I make all Button text blue?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="ManagerMenu">
    <Button x:Name="1" Content="1" />
    <Button x:Name="2" Content="2" />
    <Button x:Name="3" Content="3" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by placing a default (= without an x:Key) Button style inside the stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="ManagerMenu">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
          ... 
      </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button x:Name="1" Content="1" />
    <Button x:Name="2" Content="2" />
    <Button x:Name="3" Content="3" />
</StackPanel>
```

But you may want to base it on a pre-existing style for buttons or it will look rather flat.

Comment: When I try to add this to my StackPanel:                 `<Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ecf0f5" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10" />
                </Style> `
I get the Error: **A value of type Style cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type UIElementCollection**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a resource tag and then use this to multiple elements.
Take a look at this.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/styling-controls

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **existing style** and apply it to all buttons:

```
<StackPanel>
 <StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
 </StackPanel.Resources>
 <Button x:Name="1" Content="1" />
 <Button x:Name="2" Content="2" />
 <Button x:Name="3" Content="3" />
</StackPanel>
```